# Linux (Ubuntu) определяет HDD 6-8 Tb?

Tags: linux, hdd

Linux (Ubuntu) определяет корректно и поддерживает HDD 6-8 Tb ?

Comment: 1. так всё-таки **программа** под назанием linux или **дистрибутив операционной системы gnu/linux** под названием ubuntu? 2. о каких версиях программы linux или дистрибутива ubuntu идёт речь? 3. какой интерфейс поддерживает ваш hdd/материнская-плата/контроллер-hdd?

Comment: 1-2. linux разумеется как дистрибутив операционной системы, в частности ubuntu 16.04.3, но можно и 17 поставить, если надо..

Comment: 1. *linux разумеется как дистрибутив операционной системы* — вы сами поняли, что написали? как программа может быть дистрибутивом операционной системы? 3. про интерфейс ничего не написали // я подозреваю, что вы совсем не про то спрашиваете, про что вам **на самом деле** Требуется.

Comment: @Bl0wfish перечитал раз 5, что вы хотите выяснить так и не понял: )

Comment: Я просто хочу понять, если я поставлю ubuntu как операционную систему на комп, мать - ASUS P8Z77-V , интерфейс HDD SATA 6Gb/s ( а разве у таких дисков какой-то другой?), то распознается жесткий правильно в таком объеме или могут быть проблемы? (контроллер навскидку не знаю, гляну). Хотел уточнить на всякий случай, прежде чем покупать такой HDD

Comment: Извините, в самом вопросе изначально опечатался, вместо Gb следует читать Tb

Comment: @Bl0wfish могу сказать до 49TB проблем не было. FS - xfs, дистрибутивы Ubuntu ser 09,12,14,16 LTS

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле этот вопрос относится не к самой ОС, а к ФС, которую Вы планируете использовать на этом жёстком диске. Очевидно, что разные ФС обладают разными свойствами. Так например, для популярной файловой системы ext3, максимальный размер диска определяется размером блока:

Ограничения размеров

> Максимальное число блоков для ext3 равняется 2**32. Размер блока может
>   быть различным, что влияет на максимальное число файлов и максимальный
>   размер файла в файловой системе.

Размер блока    Макс. размер файла  Макс. размер файловой системы

- 1 KiB         16 GiB           до 2 TiB
- 2 KiB        256 GiB           до 8 TiB
- 4 KiB          2 TiB          до 16 TiB
- 8 KiB          2 TiB          до 32 TiB

Для относительно новой ФС ext4 это значение превышает всякое воображение. Она использует  48-битные номера блоков. При размере блока 4 KB это позволяет адресовать до одного эксбибайта (2^48·(4 KB) = 248·(22)·(210) B = 2^60 B = 1 EB).